# StyleGan3 error: Ninja is required to load C++ extensions

Tags: python, pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

I'm trying to run StyleGan3 code but I keep getting this error:

`RuntimeError: Ninja is required to load C++ extensions`

I did pip install Ninja and got version 1.10.2.3, and I'm on windows 10, so I installed, built and ran docker using these instructions: https://hangzhang.org/PyTorch-Encoding/notes/compile.html#using-docker

This is the full traceback I'm getting:

````
Generating image for seed 2 (0/1) ...
Setting up PyTorch plugin "bias_act_plugin"... Failed!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\stylegan3\stylegan3-main\gen_images.py", line 143, in <module>
    generate_images() # pylint: disable=no-value-for-parameter
  File "C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "C:\Users\aAppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\stylegan3\stylegan3-main\gen_images.py", line 135, in generate_images
    img = G(z, label, truncation_psi=truncation_psi, noise_mode=noise_mode)
  File "C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 727, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "<string>", line 503, in forward
  File "C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 727, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "<string>", line 143, in forward
  File "C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 727, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "<string>", line 92, in forward
  File "D:\Python\stylegan3\stylegan3-main\torch_utils\ops\bias_act.py", line 84, in bias_act
    if impl == 'cuda' and x.device.type == 'cuda' and _init():
  File "D:\Python\stylegan3\stylegan3-main\torch_utils\ops\bias_act.py", line 41, in _init
    _plugin = custom_ops.get_plugin(
  File "D:\Python\stylegan3\stylegan3-main\torch_utils\custom_ops.py", line 136, in get_plugin
    torch.utils.cpp_extension.load(name=module_name, build_directory=cached_build_dir,
  File "C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py", line 986, in load
    return _jit_compile(
  File "C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py", line 1193, in _jit_compile
    _write_ninja_file_and_build_library(
  File "C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py", line 1268, in _write_ninja_file_and_build_library
    verify_ninja_availability()
  File "C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py", line 1323, in verify_ninja_availability
    raise RuntimeError("Ninja is required to load C++ extensions")
RuntimeError: Ninja is required to load C++ extensions```
````

Comment: Could you please exact previous commands you have run? did you only ran commands under using-docker here: https://hangzhang.org/PyTorch-Encoding/notes/compile.html#using-docker ? or there are other commands?

Comment: those are the only docker commands I ran

Answer (score 0):

adding this may solve your problem

```
sudo apt-get install ninja-build
```

Comment: as I mentioned in the question, I am on windows 10, not linux.  doing pip install ninja build gives me "Error: could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ninja-build"

Answer (score 0):

You can get ninja-build on windows via [their github](https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja/releases), It's ninja-win.zip. Depending on where you install it you may have to add it to the Windows PATH.

Edit: There are instructions on building [here](https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja#building-ninja-itself)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I solved it by installing Ninja with pip:

```
pip install ninja
```

I also advise you to pay attention to this [issues](https://github.com/zhanghang1989/PyTorch-Encoding/issues/167)

Comment: it just says Requirement already satisfied: Ninja